# Java - how many string concat's should prompt the use of StringBuilder?

Tags: java, string, stringbuilder

I understand that StringBuilder should be used for concatenating multiple strings rather than using +. My question is what is the cut off point?

I have been told that if concatenating 4 or more strings you should use the StringBuilder.append(), and for anything else, use +.
Is that the case? or is the point at which stringbuilder is more efficient more than 4?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1532461/stringbuilder-vs-string-concatenation-in-tostring-in-java

Comment: It may be interesting for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7586266/is-chain-of-stringbuilder-append-more-efficient-than-string-concatenation

Answer (score 2):

As of Java 1.5, the compiler automatically uses `StringBuilder` when `+` is used in the source.

From the [Javadoc for String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/lang/String.html):

> The Java language provides special support for the string concatenation operator ( + ), and for conversion of other objects to strings. String concatenation is implemented through the StringBuilder(or StringBuffer) class and its append method.

Answer (score 2):

**Zero.**

Many years ago, in a Java version far far away (1.4), some people recommended replacing concatenation by `StringBuffer` (the thread-safe equivalent of `StringBuilder`, which had not been invented yet).

With the introduction of `StringBuilder`, and the redefinition of concatenation in terms of the faster `StringBuilder`, "optimized" code using `StringBuffer` incurred in unneeded synchronization, while non-optimal code with `+` was automatically enjoyed to the benefits of `StringBuilder`.

I would use `StringBuilder` when the concatenation is mixed with control structures or loops, or when I need to update some characters in the middle of the strings. Otherwise I assume that the compiler is smart enough to do a good job with the traditional concatenation.

Answer (score 1):

Starting in jse 5, the + sign converts to a stringbuilder during compilation.

There is a caveat to this though,  this:

```
String blam = a + b + c + d + e;
```

results in one stringbuilder and 5 appends (as expected)

This; however:

```
String blam = a;
blam += b + c;
blam := d + e;
```

results in 3 stringbuilders (one per line).

The point: + sign is fine, just stack it all in one line of code.

Comment: And in fact, in loops it makes a string builder for each concat, which could be a lot. In the case of catting in a loop, you should probably define the builder at the top of it and append on each iteration.

Comment: Correct.  do not do string concats inside loops.

Answer (score 0):

There is no *defined* answer because it's depends on `JVM` implementation. I use `StringBuilder` when I need to concat more than 3 strings.

I noticed a good case. When you need to concat `static final String`'s you don't have to use `StringBuilder`. The compliler will concat it withour performance falling:

```
final class Example {

    public static final String STRING_ONE = "string";
    public static final String STRING_TWO = "string";
    public static final String STRING_THREE = "string";
    public static final String STRING_FOUR = "string";

    public String getBigString() {
        return STRING_ONE + STRING_TWO + STRING_THREE + STRING_FOUR;    
    } 

}
```

Also I very interested in that question. I tryed to implement a good test and asked about that [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15294426/how-do-to-perform-a-good-performance-comparations-test).

Answer (score 0):

I would say that the compiler will substitute the plus with `StringBuilder` itself.

There are several situations you want to avoid in this case. For example using **+** in a loop. For each iteration a new `StringBuilder` will be created.

Might wanna read this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5430168/string-concatenation-into-stringbuilder-java)

Answer (score 0):

The compiler is pretty good at optimizing this stuff, so usually, you won't gain much. But if you're doing concatenations in a loop for instance, you might gain some benefits from using a StringBuilder instead.